# Canon PIXMA iP4700 Colour Printer vs HP Officejet J5780 All in one Printer

Tags: canon, printer

I am considering purchasing a Canon PIXMA iP4700 Colour Printer just for photographs. I have already a HP Officejet J5780 All in one Printer, which I presently use for all my printing. I find the HP a little expensive on coloured ink.
Please advise me of the benefits or otherwise regarding my purchase of the canon printer.
Not sure which would produce the better quality photographs. Would I be better buying something else?

Answer (score 1):

I use an OfficeJet 6500.   It turns out colour photos, but there is a big gap between it and lab-printed photos.   Yet lab-printed photos are not that expensive.  I use the OfficeJet for basic proofing, and order lab prints online.  I order mine from [www.photobox.ie](http://www.photobox.ie)

Comment: Thanks James, I believe we will give "photobox" a go, before trying anything else.